# Cannot get textarea value loaded with ajax using jquery in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have textarea in view which is loaded with ajax:

```
   $comments=array(
    'name'=>'comments',
    'id'=>'comments',
   ;

 <div class="form-line">
 <label for="comment"><?=lang('comment')?></label>
 <?=form_textarea($comments)?>
 </div>

 <?php echo form_submit('submit','submit',['class'=>'btn submit_comment'])?>
```

now i'm submitting and getting this value through jquery but i cannot get the value of textarea.

```
   jQuery(document).on('click','.submit_comment',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('button clicked');
        var comments=jQuery('textarea#comments').text();
       })
```

I'm getting output :
[image]

Comment: To get the content of `textarea` use `val()`.

Comment: what is output of `jQuery('textarea#comments')`. Try `console.log(jQuery('textarea#comments'))`

Comment: It is returning length: 3.

Comment: Could you please post the screenshot? It seems like it is returning array.

Comment: added in my question

Comment: The posted answer should work for you. It seems like your `textarea` do not have any content within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of textarea you need to use `.val()` instead of `.text()` like:

```
var comments = jQuery('textarea#comments').val();
console.log( comments );
```

As mentioned in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/text/):

> The `.text()` method cannot be used on form inputs or scripts. To set or get the text value of `input` or `textarea` elements, use the `.val()` method. To get the value of a script element, use the `.html()` method.

DEMO:

```js
// Set textarea value
$('#comments').val('This is some text here');

// Get textarea value
var comments = $('#comments').val();
console.log( comments );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>A Textarea Element</h1>
<textarea id="comments" rows="4" cols="50">
</textarea>
```

Comment: tried but it is not working, blank value is returned

Comment: Please check the demo. Is it working for you? You can see value is set in the textarea and we are able to get that value back also.

Comment: I have added screenshot of what i get when i run jQuery('textarea#comments')

Comment: I got your issue you have 3 elements with the same id. So, when you are trying to access the value of 2nd or 3rd element it returns the value of 1st textarea which might be blank. Please try to set different ids of each text area and test again.